# JUnit SpringBootTest postconstruct and shutdown

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-cloud

I'm trying to test a SpringBoot application that self-registers with with a `ServiceRegistry` (eg. Eureka/Consul), and then deregisters on shutdown.  The implementation simply extends pre-existing spring cloud abstractions, for example

```
@Component
public class MyAutoRegistration extends AbstractAutoServiceRegistration<MyRegistration> {

   @override
   protected void register(){...}

   @Override
   protected void deregister(){...}
```

The registration and deregistration are working as expected in sample apps, but I can't capture this in a SpringBootTest because the test runs BEFORE self-registration occurs (ie. immediately after spring context is loaded and logs shows "app started in N seconds...").  Likewise, the test finishes before the app is shutdown (ie. before spring context shutdowns), and hence before deregistration initiates.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyClientAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyRegistrationTest {

@Autowired
MyRegistration record;

@SpyBean
@Autowired
ServiceRegistry<MyRegistration> registry;

@Test
public void registers_and_deregisters(){
    verify(registry, times(1)).register(record);
    verify(registry, times(1)).deregister(record);
}
```

[Found a test class](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-commons/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/serviceregistry/AbstractAutoServiceRegistrationTests.java) that does something similar, but its a bit beyond my comprehension.  Is there a straightforward way to include auto registration/deregistration into a @SpringBootTest?

Comment: Not sure what is beyond your comprehension there, but that is testing exactly what you describe, most of the classes are just auto registration and service registry. One thing I noticed is that your test doesn't have `webEnvironment=RANDOM` defined.

Comment: sorry for delay - having SO access issues.  I will study this example - I guess my failure of comprehension is regarding the event listeners.  When I run a unit test, it exists IMMEDIATELY after spring context is created.  It does not wait for my, say, autoregistration to occur or calls annotated by @PostConstruct.  My knowledge gap is related to where you told spring to wait until autoregistration had completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red-herring... my actual problem was I did not have `spring-boot-starter-web` on my classpath, which implicitly imports `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`.  Without these, the autoregistration component that I was trying to test failed to autoconfigure.  Putting `starter-web` back on the classpath fixed my issue.